# What PVC fitting can I use to replace this cast-iron wye?

Tags: pvc

I would like to replace this old iron cast fitting. See pictures. Do they make this type of fitting in PVC? Any ideas on which fitting i can use to replace it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like 45 degree wye with a side inlet. Fit a reducer and a 45 degree street elbow on the branch.
[image]
[this part found here](https://www.globalindustrial.com/p/plumbing/fittings/PVC/06157-4-in-x-4-in-x-4-in-x-2-in-pvc-wye-w-left-side-inlet-all-hub)

Comment: This won't be a drop-in, of course. You won't find a wye with threads on it like the cast-iron one you have now. That will require an additional part. I'd try removing the brass threaded piece and using a no-hub coupler to splice in a short length of PVC pipe.